# Is WebRTC included in Chromium-Content module?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, webrtc

According to

http://www.chromium.org/developers/content-module

> The "content" module is located in src\content, and is the core code
>   needed to render a page using a multi-process sandboxed browser. It
>   includes all the web platform features (i.e. HTML5) and GPU
>   acceleration. It does not include Chrome features, i.e.
>   extensions/autofill/spelling etc. The goal is that any embedder should
>   be able to build a browser by starting with content, and then pick and
>   choose Chrome features.
>
> content vs chrome As discussed above, content should only have the
>   core code needed to render a page. Chrome features use APIs that are
>   provided by content to filter IPCs and get notified of events that
>   they require. How to Add New Features (without bloating
>   RenderView/RenderViewHost/WebContents) describes how to do this.
>
> As an example, here's a (non-exhaustive) list of features that are
>   Chrome only, and so are not in content. This means that content code
>   shouldn't have to know anything about them, only providing generic
>   APIs that they can be built upon.

- Extensions
- NaCl
- ChromeFrame
- SpellCheck
- Autofill
- Sync
- Prerendering
- Safe Browsing
- Translate

Is WebRTC included in Chromium-Content module?

I am not sure, especially, finding `jingle` directory is outside of `content`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The webrtc project is included in the `<chromium>/src/third_party/webrtc` directory.

If you are asking if the components are used in the `content_shell` target, yes they are. You have access to all the same features with regards to webrtc that you would have in Chromium proper.